# When has a nth order homogeneous ODE less than n linear independent solutions?

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As a consequence of uniqueness and existence for ODE's we know that a ODE of nth order can have no more than n linear independent solutions. 
[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191485/must-any-nth-order-homogeneous-ode-have-n-solutions) sums it up pretty well.

Unfortunately Qiaochu Yuan restricts itself to ODE with constant coefficients. Under what circumstances do we get a ODE with less than n linear independent solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The argument using the existence and uniqueness theorem (plus [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) to show that existence is global) shows that there are exactly $n$ for any $n$'th order homogeneous linear differential equation on an interval where the coefficients are continuous and the leading coefficient is nonzero.

Where you can have fewer than $n$ is when the leading coefficient is $0$ at some point in the interval.  Thus
$x^2 y'' - 2 y = 0$ has only one linearly independent solution (namely $x^2$) defined on an interval containing $0$: the general solution is $a x^2 + b/x$ which is not defined at $x=0$ if $b \ne 0$.

Comment: So assuming continuous coefficients we can, probably a bit sloppy speaking, only get less than n solution in certain points, not on a whole interval? As in your example, I can just restrict myself to an interval without {0} to get 2 lin. ind. solutions again.

Comment: Or I could just multiply by x.

Answer (score 0):

A linear ODE of nth order has always $n$ linear independent solutions.
This fact follows, for example, from the general theory of first order systems of linear equations.